# Error happens when import numpy for cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

When I use Cython in jupyter lab, an error happens.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
```

> ---
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('cython', '', 'import numpy as np\ncimport numpy as cnp\n')
>
> D:\professional\Anaconda_install\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py
>   in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)    2360
>   with self.builtin_trap:    2361                 args = (magic_arg_s,
>   cell)
>   -> 2362                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)    2363             return result    2364
>
> in cython(self, line, cell)
>
> D:\professional\Anaconda_install\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py
>   in (f, *a, **k)
>       185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
>       186     def magic_deco(arg):
>   --> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
>       188 
>       189         if callable(arg):
>
> D:\professional\Anaconda_install\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py
>   in cython(self, line, cell)
>       331         extension = None
>       332         if need_cythonize:
>   --> 333             extensions = self._cythonize(module_name, code, lib_dir, args, quiet=args.quiet)
>       334             if extensions is None:
>       335                 # Compilation failed and printed error message
>
> D:\professional\Anaconda_install\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py
>   in _cythonize(self, module_name, code, lib_dir, args, quiet)
>       422         if 'numpy' in code:
>       423             import numpy
>   --> 424             c_include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())
>       425         with io.open(pyx_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
>       426             f.write(code)
>
> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'get_include'

My numpy verison is 1.17.2 and there is no `include` folder in `D:\professional\Anaconda_install\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core`.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to make a trouble. I have just found that the numpy package crashes and the error has nothing to do with cython. After uninstall and re-install numpy, the problem can be solved.